# Copy file to SD Card in Cordova PhoneGap 2.1.0

Tags: cordova, filesystems

I'm trying to copy a file (picture) from the local cache directory of an application to the permanent storage for pictures on the SD card.  I tried searching and found examples of how to do this in Java, but I couldn't find an example of how to do this with Cordova PhoneGap.

I built the following code below following the API instructions, but I don't understand how to get the path to the pictures directory.  Also my CopyTo command doesn't seem to work correctly when using a test directory.

```
function onCameraSuccess(uri) {
    copyFileToStorage(uri);
}


var fileSystem;
var fileURI;
function copyFileToStorage(uri) {
    fileURI = uri;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSysSuccess, fsFail);
}
function onRequestFileSysSuccess(fs) {
    fileSystem = fs;
    fileSystem.root.getFile(fileURI, {create: false}, onFileEntrySuccess, fsFail);
}
function onFileEntrySuccess(fileEntry) {
    parentEntry = fileSystem.root.getDirectory("test", {create: true});
    fileEntry.copyTo(parentEntry, "file.copy", onCopyToSuccess, fsFail);
}
function onCopyToSuccess(r) {

}
function fsFail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.code);
    alert('fsFail');
}
```

Thank you for your help!
Jason

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pictures directory by call  `navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`.
 On my android device, it returns "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures". And using Cordova File API, you should be able to copy to the picture directory.